# How can I also serialize ids from elements inside form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that looks like this (for example because people can sort and add new categories/questions) :

```
<form id="lijstform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label class="lijstnaamtitle">Lijst naam</label>
            <label class="displaynonecoid" id="coid">57</label>
            <input class="form-control name_list catinput lijsttitle" type="text" name="lijsttitle">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dynamic_field" class="ui-sortable">
        <div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="2-order">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="2. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap ui-sortable-handle" id="1-order" style="">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput">
                <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="4-order" style="">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="4. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="3-order">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="3. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row sortwrap" id="5-order">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" name="category[]" placeholder="5. Voeg een categorie toe" class="form-control name_list catinput"> <i class="mdi mdi-sort dragndrop"></i>
                <div class="questionlist questionwrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <button class="btn btn-success questionbutton">Extra vraag</button>
                            <input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="1. Voeg een vraag toe" class="form-control name_list questioninput"> </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="addcategory" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove removebutton">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is how I serialize the form and post it to my PHP script:

```
$( ".lijstbutton" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // file that data is posted to:
    url = 'includes/createlist.php';
    // Serialized form
    $lijst = $( '#lijstform' ).serializeArray();
    // Id of company list is from
    $companyid = $( '#coid' ).text();
    // post the data
    var posting = $.post(url, {
      lijst: $lijst,
      companyid: $companyid
    });
    // show result in div
    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".lijstresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
    });
  });
```

With this line `$lijst = $( '#lijstform' ).serializeArray();` the entire form is serialized, but there is no id in it. I want the id of every category for example `id="1-order"`.

How can I send those ids to my PHP script so that I can store them in my order table (order as in sort order not as in a store)?

At the moment when I post to my PHP script and watch the form data this is what I see in my network tab:

```
lijst[0][name]: lijsttitle
lijst[0][value]: Lijst titel
lijst[1][name]: category[]
lijst[1][value]: Category 1
lijst[2][name]: question[]
lijst[2][value]: Question 1
lijst[3][name]: question[]
lijst[3][value]: Question 2
lijst[4][name]: category[]
lijst[4][value]: Category 2
lijst[5][name]: question[]
lijst[5][value]: Question 1
lijst[6][name]: category[]
lijst[6][value]: Category 3
lijst[7][name]: question[]
lijst[7][value]: question 1
companyid: 57
```

Comment: The only thing that is posted is form elements. So if you need something to be posted, put it in a form element.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It already is wrapped in a form tag.

Comment: But your id is on a `div`, which is not a form element. Form elements are `input`, `select`, `button`, etc.

Comment: Just add hidden input for each id